# Delete Auto-Complete Entries in Chromium

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, chromium

I have tried the solution to remove auto-complete entries mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/171198/remove-auto-complete-field-entries-in-google-chrome), but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using Chromium 7.0 on Ubuntu 10.10.

I've tried delete, shift+delete, ctrl+delete and others but none seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug: [Issue 6176: Delete key should delete the values from Autocomplete popup](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6176).

The solution seemed to have been making its way into the released version on March 2009, but seems to have lost its way. You might try to wake up the developers as regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at first - Shift-Delete didn't help (Chromium on Ubuntu 12.04), but then i've found this post https://superuser.com/a/171226/288897

Therefore, you should NOT try to delete it in the address bar, but instead locate it in the dropdown (of autocomplete) and press Shift-Delete, this should lead to the desired effect.