# How to remove all autocomplete urls with a certain url in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, autocomplete, address-bar

I am converting my `localhost:8888` to `localhost` and I want to remove all the autocomplete urls that have `localhost:8888` in them. I already did this for history but how do I do this for autocomplete? I have so many that <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> will take so much time. So is there a way I can do it for multiple at a time?

Thanks

***EDIT:*** not for username and passwords, but for urls

Comment: Did you see [Remove auto-complete field entries in Google Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/171198/remove-auto-complete-field-entries-in-google-chrome)?

Comment: not for username and password, but for urls