# Clear autofill form data - Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, auto-form-fill

Using Chrome Version 74.0.3729.157 ("re-launched" today, 5/13/2019).
I wish to clear autofill FORM data.
When I go to Settings, Advanced, Clear browsing history; Autofill form data IS checked but, clicking "Clear Data" doesn't do the job.
Oddly, supposedly there are NONE to clear. However, there are indeed NUMEROUS autofill "suggestions" every time I click in any form field. Been searching online for help/answers to no avail.
Every suggestion, except what I've tried per above, leads nowhere. Most suggestions are outdated. It is difficult to sort through & find anything current/pertinent.
Areas supposedly present just aren't such as; "Manage autofill settings" ("old").

At least, would be nice to know it is no longer possible: though cannot believe it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove auto-complete field entries in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/171198/remove-auto-complete-field-entries-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

The page [How to Delete Specific Chrome Autofill Suggestions](http://osxdaily.com/2018/07/20/how-delete-chrome-autofill-suggetsions)
shows these steps that worked well to manually remove unnecessary auto-fill data.

> 1. Open the related website which has a form entry where autofill suggestions appear
> 2. Start typing so that the suggestion shows up as an option in Chrome
> 3. Using the keyboard arrows, navigate down the suggestion list to the item(s) you want to remove from the Chrome autofill suggestions
> 4. With the suggestion highlighted, use the appropriate keystroke sequence to delete the Chrome suggestion:
>
>    - a. Mac: Shift + FN + Delete
>    - b. Windows: Shift + Delete
>    - c. Chromebook / Chrome OS: Alt + Shift + Delete
> 5. Repeat with other suggestions to delete if desired

Comment: "3. Using the keyboard arrows, navigate down the suggestion list" - You can also hover over the item with the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

If you have participated into Google sync service, you might need to turn it off first, clear 'Auto-fill form data' under "Clear browsing History", then re-check if problem persist.

Or if you need to **manually** remove unnecessary auto-fill data: http://osxdaily.com/2018/07/20/how-delete-chrome-autofill-suggetsions/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have a any idea how to prevent it from coming back when you resync?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to turn it off in Settings. Go to the 3 dots in top right corner, then click settings and Autofill should be an option. If not, search for it in settings. It should allow you to turn it off for several things like addresses, payment information, etc.

Comment: Nice of you to answer but, tried that...took those steps....nothing in that section re: forms autofill. In "Addresses & more"....there is no "more"...only addresses. And Passwords & Payment methods hold nothing additional either! Don't have a "Google Account", not intending to create one - more hoops to jump through, less privacy & that may be the "problem". Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's interesting. They are showing at the top of my settings, first page I go into. Maybe it is because I have an account or different version.

Comment: Yes, it is! I don't doubt that a bit....and yes; both could be the reason(s). Frustrating....will never understand why these issues have no simple or consistent answers. Boo, hoo!