# How can you force Chrome to forget a sensitive auto-filled piece of information such as a bank account number, Social Security Number (SSN), etc?

Tags: google-chrome, security

When filling out forms in Google Chrome, sometimes it remembers really sensitive information it should *not* remember because it considers it an "address" type field instead of a "password" or "sensitive data" type field. How can we stop this and/or delete the saved sensitive number or information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove auto-complete field entries in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/171198/remove-auto-complete-field-entries-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

[See here](https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0f8VyQ5IFDOI) (emphasis added)

> **I was able to Delete the Social Security number from being saved in the form by using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>.**
>
> Forgot that was an option... however I think it's still not very secure to save social security number form fields.

So, while typing, when you see the sensitive information pop up as an autofill option, hover your mouse over that floating text box to bring it into focus, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>. You'll see the floating suggested autofill box disappear.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to *block* this from happening in the first place, but this at least lets you delete it after it has, so long as you are in a field which triggers this recommended autocomplete information to come up again.

Comment: I'm looking for better answers than mine. Please post your own if you have something to add. I'd really like more-granular and sure control over this to verify the information is in fact gone. Any idea how to search saved address information by string?